# Which terminals are collector, emitter, and gate on this IGBT?

Tags: igbt

I am new to IGBTs. I want to experiment with them. I got this older IGBT but unfortunately have no data on it (and all the data I find on the web is fake by resellers.)

How do I know which is gate, collector, and emitter?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The schematic on the side seems to indicate that is a diode, not an IGBT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by the schematic on the side, this is not an IGBT. It's two diodes. One [source](https://wellgainelectronics.com/power-modules-cubes/38467-toshiba-160l2c43a.html) I can find corroborates this, calling it a "dual rectifier module", but it's pretty hard to find information on this part in general, for some reason.

So there is no collector, gate, or emitter. Terminal 1 is the common cathode of both diodes, and terminals 2 and 3 are their anodes.